# Pip install a package in a way that it gets not listed in requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-poetry

Is it possible to install a pip package in a way so that it gets not listed when doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt`?

I am thinkging of an equivalent to: `poetry add --dev` which adds (installs) a package as a development dependency, but it does not appear in dependency list.

Is there a way in `pip` to do something similar?

Comment: If you're using Poetry, the dependency list will be in pyproject.toml.

Comment: This I know, thanks. But I was asking myself - if there is a way in `pip` to install a package but not have it listed by `pip freeze` - kind of installing in development mode. I know, I could manually delete it from `requirements.txt` later on, but this is error prone - because sometimes one forgets to delete it.

Comment: Using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` is bad practice. You want to have complete control on what goes in your python project. requirements.txt
Modern python development as well as any JS or other production set of practices relies on package management as well as virtual environments.
Look into pipenv which handles both, installing packages only on that env and having a venv associated to it.
Otherwise, you'd have to maintain the requirements file manually everytime.

Comment: Thank you, Remzi! I will have a closer look on pipenv. However, at work, I have to know to handle requirements.txt - because I have to use RStudio connect for deployment - and it requires a requirements.txt

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim more reason to advocate for modern package control. I did a simple google search and found this article detalining on how to work with R-Studio and pipenv: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/09/python-application-deployment-with-rstudio-connect-streamlit/

Comment: @Remzi Thank you for your answer! I realize pipenv is exactly what I searched for! Please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Remzi - super helpful! Thanks! I saw here https://drgabrielharris.medium.com/python-how-create-requirements-txt-using-pipenv-2c22bbb533af that one can use pipenv to generate a requirements.txt. `pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt` exactly what I searched for. So using pipenv I can then do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).
There are ways of making RStudio work with pipenv ([link to an article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/09/python-application-deployment-with-rstudio-connect-streamlit/)).
This allows both complete package control, python version specification for a project as well as virtualenv, all in one.
Otherwise, you'd have to maintain your requirements.txt file manually, and further down the line use a [constraints.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files) file, also.

Think of pipenv files as what yarn.lock files (JS) vs package.json file + some extra sweet features.

You can use pipenv to generate a requirements.txt file by doing:

```
pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

While you can add/install packages in development mode by:

```
pipenv install --dev <mypackage>
```